# Can we use bearer tokens with jetty jsessionid?

Tags: authorization, jetty, session-cookies, bearer-token, jsessionid

I understand that jetty 9.4 SessionHandler supports jsessionid either as matrix parameter in url or as a COOKIE.

Is it possible to support jsessionid in http request headers for example "Authorization" header ?

I could not find good documentation in jetty to override default behavior to handle session/jsessionid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session ID is not related to authentication or authorization.

Session ID can (and does) change throughout the lifespan of a single `HttpSession`, attempting to tie it to a specific value like a bearer token is unwise.

Lastly, the client does not determine the Session ID, the server does.  The server creates / assigns / manages it, and just lets the client know what it is.